# If $\lim \sup|a_n|^{1/n}=1$, and $b_n=a_0+a_1+\dots+a_n$, $c_n=\frac{1}{n+1}(b_0+b_1+\dots+b_n)$, prove $\lim\sup |c_n|^{1/n}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have proved $\lim\sup |b_n|^{1/n}\ge 1$.

I think then I should prove $\lim\sup |b_n|^{1/n}\le 1$, and get $\lim\sup |b_n|^{1/n}=1$, then use this result to prove $\lim\sup |c_n|^{1/n}$, but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Did you miss $a_1$ in $b_n$ or is it really defined without $a_1$?

Comment: @LucasHenrique So sorry, Edited

Comment: My first thought on seeing the problem statement: if $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is a series with radius of convergence 1, then $h(z)$ which is an antiderivative of $\frac{f(z)}{(1-z)^2}$ should also have radius of convergence 1.  (Requires a bit of elementary complex analysis, though - I don't know if that's in OP's toolbox.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler The title is actually from a complex analysis question, which says $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence 1, then to prove $g(z)=\sum c_nz^n$ also has radius of convergence 1.

Comment: OK, for a more elementary argument, I think I would start out by fixing $\varepsilon > 0$, and then for sufficiently large $n$ you have $|a_n|^{1/n} < 1 + \varepsilon$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ease discussion, we start the sequence with subscript $1$. I assume
that $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots$ are complex numbers. Define $\gamma_{n}=\frac{1}{n}(a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots a_{n})$.
Suppose that $\limsup_{n}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

---

Claim 1: $\limsup_{n}|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq1.$

Proof of Claim 1: Let $r>1$ be arbitrary. Since $\limsup_{n}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1<r$,
there exists $N_{1}$ such that $|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}<r$ whenever
$n\geq N_{1}$. That is, $|a_{n}|<r^{n}$ for all $n\geq N_{1}$.
Let $M=\max_{k<N_{1}}|a_{k}|$. For any $n\geq N_{1}$, we have estimation
\begin{eqnarray*}
|\gamma_{n}| & \leq & \frac{M}{n}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_1}^{n}|a_{k}|}{n}\\
 & \leq & \frac{M}{n}+\frac{r^{N_1}+r^{N_1+1}+\ldots+r^{n}}{n}\\
 & \leq & \frac{M}{n}+r^{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $\alpha>1$ be arbitrary. Observe that $\frac{M}{nr^{n}}\rightarrow0<\alpha-1$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so we can choose $N_{2}>N_{1}$ such that
$\frac{M}{nr^{n}}<\alpha-1$ whenever $n\geq N_{2}$. That is, $\frac{M}{n}+r^{n}<\alpha r^{n}$
whenever $n\geq N_{2}$. Hence, for $n\geq N_{2}$, $|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}r$.
Therefore $\limsup_{n}|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\limsup_{n}\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}r=\lim_{n}\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}r=r$.
Since $r>1$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\limsup_{n}|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq1$.

---

Claim 2: $\limsup_{n}|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq1$.

Proof of Claim 2: Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that
$\limsup_{n}|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}<1$. Choose $s$ such that
$\limsup_{n}|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}<s<1$. Then there exists $N_{1}$
such that $|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}<s$ whenever $n\geq N_{1}$.
That is, $|\gamma_{n}|<s^{n}$. For $n\geq N_{1}$, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
|a_{n+1}| & = & \left|(n+1)\gamma_{n+1}-n\gamma_{n}\right|\\
 & \leq & (n+1)|\gamma_{n+1}|+n|\gamma_{n}|\\
 & \leq & (n+1)s^{n+1}+ns^{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Observe that $\frac{(n+1)s^{n+1}}{ns^{n}}\rightarrow s<1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$,
so there exists $N_{2}>N_{1}$ such that $\frac{(n+1)s^{n+1}}{ns^{n}}<1$
whenever $n\geq N_{2}$. Therefore, for $n\geq N_{2}$, we have that
$|a_{n+1}|\leq2ns^{n}$. It follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\limsup_{n}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}} & \leq & \limsup_{n}\left\{ 2ns^{n}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\\
 & = & \lim_{n}\left\{ 2ns^{n}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\\
 & = & s.
\end{eqnarray*}
by observing that $n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\rightarrow1$ and $s^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\rightarrow s$.
This is a contradiction because it is given that $\limsup_{n}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

---

Hence, we have proven that:

Proposition: Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Let
$\gamma_{n}=\frac{1}{n}(a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n})$. If $\limsup_{n}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$,
then $\limsup_{n}|\gamma_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

---

We apply the Proposition to your problem. To ease discussion, I assume
that $b_{n}=a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n}$ and $c_{n}=\frac{1}{n}(b_{1}+\ldots+b_{n})$.

Suppose that $\limsup_{n}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$. By the Proposition,
we have that $\limsup_{n}|b_{n}/n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$. However, since
$(\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow1$, we have that $\limsup_{n}|b_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup_{n}|b_{n}/n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

Invoke the Proposition on the sequence $(b_{n})$, then we have $\limsup_{n}|c_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.